# How can I convert an image to grayscale without losing any transparency?

Tags: python, opencv

This is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread(some_path, 0)
```

Original image:

[image: PNG image]

After running the code:

[image: PNG image grayscale]

Obviously losing a lot of transparency.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PILLOW:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('image_to_grayscale.png').convert('LA')
img.save('greyscale.png')
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: The best solution found.